# JSP page not displaying output

Tags: jsp, ms-access, database-connection

I want to display ID in my table in access database. My code is running without any error.

But the code does not display anything. Only the white screen in Html page.

Here is my code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
<body>

<%
    try
    {
        Connection con = null;
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:AccessDatabase", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String str= "SELECT * FROM emp_table";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);

    while(rs.next())
    {
%>
        <%= rs.getInt("ID") %>
<%
    }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
}
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you have only one record in the  **emp_table** , and when you call rs.next for first it is accessing the iterator obj(ResultSet ) but you are not using it properly.

try this,

```
 while(rs.hasnext())
        {
    %>    yourDatabaseObj = rs.next(); 

            <%= yourDatabaseObj.getInt("ID") %>
    <%
        }
```

Comment: My problem has been solved. I put the database file in the ROOT folder of Apache where my jsp file is, i.e 
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.18\webapps\ROOT...